# How I can generate statistics for my less used columns of a specific table in my database?

Tags: postgresql

I want to remove unused information stored in some columns in a table. The table though is undocumented and I gradually try to find out what column is used for.

A better view upon table usage is to find which columns of this tablwe are less used so I can further investigate the use of them.

What I want to find out are columns that are written once and rarely are being used in Select or update statements. Is there a way to find out this information from `information_schema`?

I am using postgresql

Comment: Use pgaudit to write alerts to the log file whenever something accesses the relevant column.  Be patient, though, since a column might only be used once a month or less, but is **vital** when needed.

Comment: Even worse, there might be a legal requirement to keep the data for 7 years.

Comment: Unless it’s a blob column using a significant amount of disk space, just leave it alone.

Comment: @RonJohn well yeah I keep note on that.

Comment: Also @RonJohn I jave a vague idea about the db therefore I can target to speficic tables that I can know that receive frequent inserts and updates.